# Stack Snippet com erro (500 internal error server)

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Ao acessar seja qualquer stack snippet no site estou obtendo o erro:

> [image: stack snippet erro 500]

Comment: Outro dia eu estava tendo esse erro direto, depois do nada melhorou...

Comment: Ué, -1 por que? Isso é um BUG relatado, inclusive foi relatado no SOen também por outro usuário, só pode ser falta de noção mesmo.

Comment: Isso foi relatado [aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366505/stack-snippets-is-down-again). A equipe de arquitetura está ciente do bug e está tentando corrigi-lo. Obrigado por denunciar!